# What are the columns from object Dump of a C object?

Tags: c, object

Using `objdump -S --disassemble hello`, I get some output like this:

```
000000000000064a <main>:
 64a:   55                      push   %rbp
 64b:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 64e:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
 652:   c7 45 f4 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0xc(%rbp)
 659:   c7 45 f8 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,-0x8(%rbp)
 660:   8b 55 f4                mov    -0xc(%rbp),%edx
 663:   8b 45 f8                mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
 666:   01 d0                   add    %edx,%eax
 668:   89 45 fc                mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
 66b:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
 66e:   89 c6                   mov    %eax,%esi
 670:   48 8d 3d 9d 00 00 00    lea    0x9d(%rip),%rdi        # 714 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
 677:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 67c:   e8 9f fe ff ff          callq  520 <printf@plt>
 681:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 686:   c9                      leaveq 
 687:   c3                      retq   
 688:   0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 68f:   00
```

Whats in the respective columns? I get that at the very end after `#` is a comment. What does `55` mean for `push`?

Answer (score 1):

These fields are:

- `000000000000064a <main>`: address of symbol and <symbol>
- `64a`: Address in hex
- `55`:  [Opcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opcode) bytes in hex, i.e. machine code of the instruction.
- `push`: mnemonic of instruction opcode
- `%rbp`: operand(s) of instruction

The opcode bytes may span two lines, e.g.

```
401230:       c7 05 da 5f 20 00 01    movl   $0x1,0x205fda(%rip)
401237:       00 00 00
```

Comment: OK, but not every `mov` must have the same Opcode? See eg. `660` and `663`.

Comment: @TMOTTM Of course not, these instructions have different operands (which are usually considered part of the instruction).